# Store value of a javascript dependent dropdown menu in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

By this code is saving the values of departments but not of degree. All work is fine except that the degree value is not saving into mysql.  I'm using PHP

HTML

```
<select class ="form-control" name="department">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
  <option value="Applied-Psychology">Applied Psychology</option>
  <option value="Botany">Botany</option>
  <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
  <option value="Computer-Science">Computer Science</option>
  <option value="English">English</option>
  <option value="Islamiyat">Islamiyat</option>
  <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
  <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
  <option value="Urdu">Urdu</option>
  <option value="Zoology">Zoology</option>
</select>
<select name="degree" id="degree">
  <option value="BS" class="Botany Zoology Applied-Psychology Computer-Science Mathematics Chemistry English Islamiyat Urdu Statistics">BS</option>
  <option value="MS" class="Chemistry">MS</option>
  <option value="M.Sc" class="Botany Zoology Applied-Psychology Computer-Science Mathematics Chemistry">M.Sc</option>
  <option value="M.A" class="English Islamiyat Urdu">M.A</option>
  <option value="M.Phil" class="Botany Zoology Chemistry English Islamiyat Urdu">M.Phil</option>
  <option value="Ph.D" class="Botany Zoology Chemistry English Islamiyat Urdu">Ph.D</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
    var degree = $("[name=degree] option").detach()
$("[name=department]").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val()
  $("[name=degree] option").detach()
  degree.filter("." + val).clone().appendTo("[name=degree]")
}).change()
document.getElementById('degree').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('You selected: ', this.value);
});
```

PHP

```
$department = $_POST['department'];
$degree=$_POST['degree'];
```

Comment: echo $_POST['degree'] and see if it has the value you expect. If it does, you'll need to post more code including your SQL query.

Comment: @Matt i run it again and actually its now taking all other degrees except M.Sc... i dont know why even though im using the same format for it too..

Answer (score 0):

just debug in your javascript function that you are getting value of degree select box

As per your example just first alert the degree value

```
alert($("[name=degree] option").detach());
```

Or you can check like

```
alert($( "#degree" ).val());
```

if you get the value in this then continue with your code

Comment: degree.filter("." + val).clone().appendTo("[name=degree]")
}).change(), Can you let me know why you are appending here? is there any functionality? Or you just need to get selected values of degree and department in POST?